# session expires and so does my cookie

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have set cookie and set it to expire after sufficient seconds. Still as soon as my session expires the cookie also expires. This is my code :-

```
   if(isset($_POST['KeepMesignedIn'])) {
                    $this->load->helper('cookie');
                    $cookie = array(
                            'name'   => 'info',
                            'value'  =>  $user->Username . '||' . $user->Password,
                            'expire' => time()+3600*24*30
                    );

                    set_cookie($cookie);
                }
```

Can anybody identify the problem?

Comment: Do *NOT* store the password in a cookie. That’s what sessions are for.

Comment: Cookies are client side. They are sent, unencoded with every HTTP request. Not the safest place to be storing/ sending a user's password.

Comment: @Gumbo :- If i do not store passwords in cookie then how can i implement Keep me signed on feature? Also cookies are encrypted by default in codeigniter. So that shouldn't be a problem. Can it be?

Comment: @Ankit Rathod: Use a session that holds the state of “being logged in”. And according to CodeIgniter’s user guide, you can only encrypt the cookie that holds the session information.

Comment: @Gumbo :- I do not understand. Generally sessions expire after 30-60 mins. I want that even when users log in after 15 days if they have cookies set they should be logged in directly. Obviously i can't hold the session of all users for 15 days. Can i?

Comment: @Ankit There are much, MUCH better ways to keep people signed in. Storing the user/password in a cookie is one of the stupidest ways because then anyone who looks the cookies can see the password. ALSO, even if CodeIgniter encrypts the cookie, it can be unencrypted. If the hacker really wants to, he can unencrypt it **just** like CodeIgniter and get the password.

Comment: @Ankit http://php.net/session_set_cookie_params

Comment: @Chacha :- Can you suggest me how if you don't mind so that i can improve my code? I want my users to be always logged in once they have logged in my site.

Comment: @Ankit Rathod: That purpose does not justify storing the user’s credentials neither. Use some kind of one-time authentication token instead.

Comment: @Chacha :- Does this function mean sessions will always be active on server and occupy unnecessary resources for the duration of 1st parameter of lifetime? In my case 2-3 months?

Comment: @Gumbo :- Thanks Gumbo. I will be glad to do that if you can just point me to some link where i can get more help.

Comment: @Ankit Rathod: In general, this kind of “remember me” functionality makes it easier to steal someone’s session and thus his/her identity (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594960/best-practice-to-implement-secure-remember-me). So you should be aware of that higher thread level (see also http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_Authentication#Remember_Me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the CodeIgniter documentation, [`set_cookie`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html) expects *expires* to be the delta seconds that are added to the current time:

> The expiration is set in **seconds**, which will be added to the current time. Do not include the time, but rather only the number of seconds from *now* that you wish the cookie to be valid. If the expiration is set to zero the cookie will only last as long as the browser is open.

Answer (score 0):

check is this part of code executed in your app or not. You need to debug.