# Saving User Information in a Cookie

Tags: php, mysql

When a user selects the remember me function, I save his username and id in a cookie. Then, when the user returns to the site, I check the username and id against a database to ensure that the user is legitimate. I next log the user in by storing the cookie data in the session variable. Is this the proper way to remember and log in a user?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594960/best-practice-to-implement-secure-remember-me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookies are not a very secure way of storing data.  The cookies can be modified by a user and could lead to someone "hacking" into your site.  What I would suggest is store a string in the cookie that is some hash of something.  Also store the hashed string from the cookie in your database.  This way when a user returns to the site, you check to see if the cookie is filled, match it to the hashed value in the database and then find who owns that hashed value.  If all is valid, log them in.

**Database setup**

```
secretKey PK varchar
userid (could be unique) int
validUntil int or date/time
  //If userID is unique you will have to remove this row from the 
  // database when a new key is made for the user,  This would then mean
  // that a user would only be allowed to be rememberd on one computer
```

**pseudocode**

```
//User logs in with remember me
    //set cookie to something like md5(userid,username,timestamp)
    //store the md5 in the database layout
//User Returns to site
    //check to see if cookie is set
        //if cookie set
            //find md5 in database which is logged with user id
            //if found and not yet expired log in
            //else show login page
        //if cookie not set show login page
```

In the valid until field you would set it to say 2 weeks from login.  once the valid until has passed, do not let that key work and make sure the cookie is expired for the user.

**query to check login**

SELECT * FROM rememberMe WHERE key="//put md5 here" AND validUntil > time()

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying, but how do I handle the validUntil field? What do I do when that date passes?

Comment: Should this secretKey field be in the table with all of my users, or should there be a new table for secretKeys?

Comment: You could put it in with your users. but if it was me doing this, i would create a different table and just join the members table into it

Answer (score 2):

No.

It depends on just how secure you want to get.  Here are some things you can do (some or all of them) to increase security:

- Do not store anything specific in the cookie (username/id/etc.).  Use randomly generated nonsense (token).

  1. In your DB you can have a token <-> user mapping
  2. Check the token against your DB and log the user in when there's a match
  3. Destroy the token (flag it as "consumed," perhaps to be deleted later.  Whatever you decide, the token shouldn't work anymore).
- Use `https` only to transmit the cookies, login, etc.
- If a user sends a stale token (i.e. one that is not in your DB, or that has been flagged as consumed) this means that it's possible the token has been compromised.  On every request for authenticated users (and perhaps even with ajax), compare the token they logged in with (you can store it in the session) with a list of stale token attempts.  If there is a match, this means it's likely that the authenticated user has hijacked the token.  Kick them out.